# Computationally bind styles in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

Using Angular5 - I know how it is possible to bind an HTML element's style to a Boolean value, but I can't find an explanation to do this for multiple styles at the same time.

ie. I have found something like this works fine:

```
[style.background]="r.favourite === true ? '#3f51b5' : 'white'"
```

However I am also wanting to change the color of my text to white at this point also... And I don't want to clutter my components with lots of [style.xxx] tags.

Is there a way I can dynamically bind to a CSS class to apply when `r.favourite === true`?

I have seen ways in which this can be done... However this assumes you are binding within the same file as such:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `

    <button class="my-btn" [class.extraclass]="someProperty">Call to Action</button>
`,
    styles: [`
    .my-btn { font-size:1.7em; }
    .extraclass { background: black; color: white; }
    `]
})

export class AppComponent { 

    someProperty = true;

}
```

However my CSS is being stored in a shared file - such that I have a file structure like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    styleUrls: ['./css/shared-styles.css']
    template: `

    <button class="my-btn" [class.extraclass]="someProperty">Call to Action</button>
`
})

export class MyComponent { 
    someProperty = true;
}
```

Comment: `<div [ngClass]="{'YourClass': YourBoolean}">...</div>`

Comment: Hi @Flow - I just updated my question to say that I am storing CSS in an external file used as a shared repo for multiple components... Would this still work?

Comment: yes it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NgClass.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'text-success':r.favourite ,'text-danger':!r.favourite}">
```

Where 'text-success' and 'text-danger' are classes you define.
Please refer to this great article about NgClass and NgStyle:
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/

Hope this helps

Comment: I just updated my question to say that I am storing CSS in an external file used as a shared repo for multiple components... Would this still work?

Comment: Yes as long as your component has access to that css file.

Comment: Also... Could you not define your answer with a Ternary operator? Such as: `[ngClass]="{ r.favourite === true ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger' }`?

Comment: I will give it a try and see how it comes out!

Comment: There's no need to use it, because ngClass allows you to define as much conditions as you want.

Comment: Ah, sorted! Thanks a lot for that. I knew it was something like this, but couldn't put my finger on it.
In the end I went for `[ngClass]="{'someClass':r.favourite===true}"`